# how to add images into folder using laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel-4

Iam new in laravel. 1st Im create a  new folder (gallery) in public/img/uploads/gallery.
code is `$f1=Input::get('f1');
          $path ='img/uploads/'.$f1;
          File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);`
Then Im trying to insert image to this gallery folder. 
1st Im create a select box to etch all the folders from public/img/uploads/ using this code `{ Form::select('f1', $list, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`
and enter gallery name(textbox) ,browse image(file).then im submit. the details are goto database .but the image not go to gallery folder ,but create a new folder &image save into that folder. using controller.php is here `else
       {    $f1=Input::get('f1');
            $file=File::directories('/img/uploads/', '=', $f1)->first();

            $file=Input::file('galimg');
            $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('img/uploads/'.$f1,$filename);
              ForumGallery::create([
             'galname'=>Input::get('galname'),
             'galimg'=>$f1.'/'.$filename
              ]);return Redirect::route('addnewgallery')
            ->with('success',' Gallery Details Entered succesfully');}`
i Want image save into gallery(selcted) folder and databse.
 How to save image into selected folder??

Comment: You need to shave the actual source code, not just a `<link>` tag to your JavaScript or CSS file.

Comment: these 2 files are save into public folder. im just call the dashboard.blade.php page.                                 public/css/prettyphoto.css javascript file and public/js/jquery.prettyphoto.js jquery files